# Change background image of one element to the same image of the other element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm currently working on a nail polish website and am very new to Jquery.  I need to implement a "try it on" page where people can select a colour they like and the nails of the image change to that specific colour.

Basically like this: http://chinaglaze.com/Try-On/index.html

I've tried pulling the html, scripts etc from this link to try figure out how it's been done.  However, I have absolutely no idea how to implement this and get it working on my site.

I've been doing a a lot of research and cannot find the answer.

Okay so the hand is a div with a .png background image implemented via css (the nails are transparent).  The buttons next to the hand are plain images.  Basically when someone selects the specific button image, it must then pull to the div as a background image and repeat.  Thus showing through as the nail colour.

I'm not sure if this makes any sense?

Comment: can you show your effort in a JSFiddle ? should be easy enough to do after.

Comment: at least show us your html. anwser should be very easy.

Comment: The way they've done this is using 2 images. The first image is the hand and it's on top. The nails are transparent areas (it's a PNG). The second image is a square that is the polish color/pattern. This is applied underneath the image of the hand so you see the pattern through the transparent nails. All they're doing when you click a color on the right hand side is switching the background image of the color/pattern div.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample snippet for how to set colour of one item on another on click.
(Since you have not provided any HTML i have used a sample mark up)

In the link you have provided they might be using image instead.

```js
$(".item").click(function() {

  $("#change").css("background",$(this).css("background"));
});
```

```css
#change {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline block;
  float: left
}
#green {
  background: green;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
}
#yellow {
  background: yellow
}
#black {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="change">
  Select a color
</div>

<div class="item" id="green">
</div>
<div class="item" id="red">
</div>
<div class="item" id="blue">
</div>
<div class="item" id="yellow">
</div>
<div class="item" id="black">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone for your help.  I'm looking to use a repeated image rather than a colour with the onclick function. (Basically when someone selects the specific button image, it must then pull to the div as a background image and repeat. Thus showing through as the nail colour.)  

This is what I have pulled:

Comment: <div id="changer">
<div id="screen"></div>
<div id="changer_right">
<div id="color_dot"><img id="dots" src="http://chinaglaze.com/uploads/products/dots_sm/81127.png" alt="" data-likes="105" data-name="Creative Fantasy" data-sku="81127" data-id="525" />
<span style="display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block;">
</div>
</div>

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution, used the code from above answer and created a working [JSFiddle][1] with few changes

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  $(".screen").css("background",$(this).css("background"));
});
```

```css
.screen {
    
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#change
{
   background:url("http://chinaglaze.com/images/tryon/hand_1.png") 0px 0px no-repeat;
     width: 300px;
    height: 516px;
}
.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline block;
  float: left;
  
}
#green {
  background: green;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
}
#yellow {
  background: yellow
}
#black {
  background: black
}
```

```html
   

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="screen">
  <div id="change">
    Select a color
  </div>
</div>


<div class="item" id="green">
</div>
<div class="item" id="red">
</div>
<div class="item" id="blue">
</div>
<div class="item" id="yellow">
</div>
<div class="item" id="black">
</div>
```